# Calculate number of squares from a rectangle

Tags: php

I'm working on some PHP code but I'm stuck with a logic.
I need to find out the number of squares from a rectangle.

I'm unable to implement this in PHP.

Please help.

I tried this:

```
function getcount($length,$breadth,$count=0){
  $min=min($length,$breadth);
  if($length>$breadth){
    $length=$length-$min;
    $count++;
    return getcount($length,$breadth,$count);
  }
  else if($breadth>$length){
    $breadth=$breadth-$min;
    $count++;
    return getcount($length,$breadth,$count);
  }
  else{
    $count+=($length/$min);
  }
  return $count;
}
```

But some how it doesn't pass all the use cases.
And i do not know on which use cases, it fails?

Comment: Sorry for this but can't resist. Homework ?

Comment: @mleko No. It's not :)  An example in my training.

Comment: Have you tried anything? If you have, please [edit] your question to include your solution (however faulty)

Comment: Think recursive: for any rectangle (e.g.5x3), you can remove a square equal to the size of the width (e.g. 3x3).... this leaves you with a rectangle (or in a few cases a square) of 2x3.... recurse for this new rectangle, and continue recursing until the remaining rectangle is 0x0... the number of squares is equal to the maximum number of levels of recursion

Comment: If it's training then giving you an answer won't help you. Any ideas how you could solve this?

Comment: @mleko I tried. Please check the question now. I edited it.

Comment: @SecondRikudo Please check question

Comment: @sash if you know how to use debugger, try it and check how this program works. If not, this using echo or print_r to get some idea what it is actually doing. I really don't want to tell you, "HERE IS MISTAKE".

Comment: @mleko Can you post here an example when this code fails? For `echo getcount(5, 3);` it returns `4` which is correct.

Comment: @sash I'm quite sure it was meant for you.

Comment: @sash I have a question. When this program will enter else(the last one)?

Comment: @mleko when it's a square (`$breadth == $length`).

Comment: @PetrR. I'm aware of that :)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I think the easiest way to calculate the number of squares in a rectangle is to substract the found squares from it while it disappears completely.

It works fine for me:

```
function getcount($width,$height) {
    $total=0;
    while($width && $height)
    {
        if($width>$height)
        {
            $width-=$height;
        }
        else if($height>$width)
        {
            $height-=$width;
        }
        else
        {
            $width=0;
            $height=0;
        }
        $total+=1;
    }
    return $total;
}

echo getcount(5,3)."<br/>";
echo getcount(5,5)."<br/>";
echo getcount(11,5)."<br/>";
```

Output:

```
4
1
7
```

Answer (score 0):

In my opinion there is nothing wrong in your code. The output from the code in OP is exactly the same as the output of the code in [the accepted answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23242212/1935077). You can run this *(where `getcount()` is the function from OP and `getcount2()` is the function from [the Balázs Varga's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23242212/1935077))*:

```
for ($i=0; $i<10000; $i++)
{
    $a=mt_rand(1,50);
    $b=mt_rand(1,50);
    $r1 = getcount($a, $b);
    $r2 = getcount2($b, $b);
    if ($r1 != $r2)
    {
        echo "D'oh!";  
    }
}
```

and it will not return anything at all.

The only flaw is your code will throw a warning message when you run `getcount(0, 0)`. 
Also, the second line in your code *(`$min=min($length,$breadth);`)* is a bit redundant. You can write the same this way:

```
function getcount($length,$breadth,$count=0){
    if($length>$breadth){
        $length=$length-$breadth;
        $count++;
        return getcount($length,$breadth,$count);
    }
    else if($breadth>$length){
        $breadth=$breadth-$length;
        $count++;
        return getcount($length,$breadth,$count);
    }
    else if ($breadth!=0){
        $count++; // there is no need to divide two same numbers, right?
    }
    return $count;
}
```